# How to equal Browser capability between Ie8 & Ie7

Tags: html, css

How do I equal Browser capability between Ie8 & Ie7? How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these: [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/),  [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org),  [Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Answer (score 1):

This resource on [HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to use dean edwards scripts: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/